# Tool for launching command on files with same date

Tags: bash, command

I have several set of files (several hundreds). In each set, each file is related to a date (year/month/day) that is encoded in the file name. I want to execute a command that takes in input a file from each set for a particular date.
Since files are sometime missing in some sets, I want to only launch the command when all sets contain a file for a particular date.

I would to know if there is any existing (command line or other) tool that can do this kind of thing. I searched but I could not find anything.
The use of date as key for files is not mandatory. I guess that any tool that is generic enough will provide a way to specify the key as a parameter.

Edit:

- There are less than 10 sets but each contain several hundreds of files.
- Each set is located in a separate directory.

Comment: This seems like a pretty specialized requirement, I've never heard of a tool for it.

Comment: Do you have several sets or several hundred sets?  Do they have distinct filenames or are they in separate directories or...?  How is the date encoded in the filename?

Comment: Is the task "do any files exist for this given date" or "are there dates for which files exist"? If the latter, what's the date range?

Comment: Well, the task is more: here are these datasets, find the intersection in terms of dates, and for each date that is in the intersection, launch a specific single command that use a file from each dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Since this answer is tagged with bash, here is a bash script to check if a file exists containing some date string (provided as the first argument of the script) in each of the given sets.  If it exists in every one, then some_command is executed:

```
#!/bin/bash
datestr=$1
all_exist=Y
for set in dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4
do
    [ -f "$set/"*"$datestr"* ] || all_exist=""
done
[ "$all_exist" ] && some_command
```

Comment: The wildcards cannot be quoted.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

So this can really be divided into two tasks:

- Find dates for which a set exists
- Launch a command on each set

You are not revealing how your files are organized, but if you have something like `boom20140112/a.txt` and `boom20140112/b.txt` forming one set, and `foo20140111/a.txt` and `foo20140111/c.txt` another, you can find the dates with

```
dates () {
    printf "%s\n" *201[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/. |
    sed -e 's%^[0-9]*%%' -e 's%/\.$%%' |
    sort -u
}
```

If your sets look different, you can probably adapt this.  The general idea is to obtain a list of pertinent file names, strip out the parts which aren't the date, and remove any duplicates.  Now you have a list of dates.

Here is another implementation which assumes that you have files named `tags/tags_(date)_a.txt` and `tags/tags_(date)_b.txt` and `input/samples_(date).txt` forming one set per date, where date is formatted like 2014-01-12.

```
dates () {
    printf "%s\n" input/* tags/* |
    sed 's/.*_\(201[1-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]\)[_.].*/\1/' |
    sort -u
}
```

Given that, loop over the dates and run your command on each set.

```
dates | while read -r date; do
    command *$date/*
done
```

Comment: It's easy to adapt to other file naming patterns, but I didn't want to make this too abstract. If you can document what your sets actually look like, we can work towards a solution which works for exactly that scenario.